# changing the font size of radio button text

Tags: html

I am trying to change the font-size of some radio buttons :

```
<input type="radio" name="rdDate" id="ShowAll" value="Show All" style="border-style:none;margin-left:0px;font-size:11px;"/>Show All
    <input type="radio" name="rdDate" id="ShowCurrent" value="Show Current" style="border-style:none;font-size:11px;"/>Show Current
```

But adding style="font-size:11px;" to the input tag does not change the text size.  The only way I have found to do this is to wrap the text in a font tag, but then you are limited to a font size of 1 to 7, none of which is the right size for what I require.

Does anybody know how to change the font size of a radio button text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The text is *beside* the radio button, not inside it.

First, add a `<label>` element (make sure the `for` attribute matches the `id` of the input with which it is associated, this will link them so people will have a bigger click target and screen reader users will know which label belongs with which control).

Then *style the label*.

Comment: For explanation: The `for`-attribute has to be the same like the `name`-attribute of your input. Those should be renamed into `rdDate1` and `rdDate2` in order to work properly.

Comment: @Tim — No! The `id` attribute! If you change the names then the radio buttons won't be a group any more!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text with a `<label>` tag and then you can style up this tag.

```
<input type="radio" name="rdDate" id="ShowAll" value="Show All" style="border-style:none;margin-left:0px;font-size:11px;"/><label style="font-size: 11px;">Show All</label>
<input type="radio" name="rdDate" id="ShowCurrent" value="Show Current" style="border-style:none;font-size:11px;"/><label style="font-size: 11px;">Show Current</label>
```

Also consider NOT using inline styles and use an external stylesheet.